# javascript code to obtain body text of a web page in a specified iframe in Google Chrome web browser

Tags: google-chrome

I want to obtain the text of an iframe in Google Chrome using Javascript. (I will pass this text using a chrome extension to a google app engine application, which will then do processing using the data received). Also, can you also tell me how to encode this into JSON format and send this data as part of a call to external web application? (Although if you can only tell me how to obtain body text that will also be good enough for me :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done similar work in my extension. I just put this

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

in my contentscript.js, and this is part of my manifest.json

```
"content_scripts" : [
{
  "matches" : [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "js" : ["contentscript.js"],
  "run_at" : "document_idle",
  "all_frames" : true
}
```

],

Comment: i also want to send the content of 10 iframes' web pages to a form so that the form can do further processing on this data... Can you tell me how to send this data?

Comment: Could you give more precise example for your question?